# Strategy for location and datetime to calculate the timezone inc handling DST

Tags: c#, timezone-offset

Ok I have an issue where I want a user interface to enter date/time for an arbitrary location on Earth. Basically I can put in my system some sort of location information to allow me to calculate the timezone for that "place". I want my UI to display the datetime entered in the location's relevant timezone setting **for that specified date**.

Is there a .NET API for calculating what the timezone is for a location at a specified datetime? I don't want the *current* timezone. I want the timezone for a *specified DateTime*.

E.g. in Australia AEDST, in Sydney, TZ is +11GMT today. 3 months ago it was AEST ie +10GMT. If someone enters a DateTime in of say 15/07/2020 09:00:00, I want the control to display that exact DateTime but I will store 15/07/2020 09:00:00+10:00. How do I determine what timezone Sydney had at that date?

EDIT: solution needs to be offline

Comment: Are you looking for [`GetUtcOffset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.getutcoffset?view=netcore-3.1#System_TimeZoneInfo_GetUtcOffset_System_DateTime_)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086962/how-to-get-a-time-zone-from-a-location-using-latitude-and-longitude-coordinates   Get time zone from location.

Comment: @MikeJ a marvellous link!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a time zone from a location using latitude and longitude coordinates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086962/how-to-get-a-time-zone-from-a-location-using-latitude-and-longitude-coordinates)

Comment: @MikeJ Thanks for the link! I am parsing through it for the strategy. I'm thinking I can store IANA tz name against my resources as a first step. Then when a datetime is entered, I will use the tz name and the date info to calculate what the offset is which I'm trying to piece together now.

Comment: @Shiv great!  If you feel your question would benefit from an explicit answer not fully covered in the link, feel free to post it as an answer below

Answer (score 0):

Solution workflow:

1. Store IANA tz name against a resource e.g. "Australia/Sydney"
2. Have a date control specify a transaction record against that resource (e.g. using a standard DateTime control). For argument sake let's say 13/12/2020 (dd/MM/yyyy) specified. This would be +11GMT in AEDST. Need to offline calculate how to get from "13/12/2020" + "Australia/Sydney" => storing "2020-12-13T00:00:00+11:00" in DateTimeOffset field.

Use

```
TimeZoneInfo tzi = TZConvert.GetTimeZoneInfo("Australia/Sydney");
```

to get timezone info.

Then for an arbitrary date, calculate offset

```
TimeSpan offsetTest = tzi.GetUtcOffset(new DateTime(2020, 7, 1));
```

The final component of the design will be the ambiguous time period where DST changes over. I would probably choose and arbitrary valid result for GetUtcOffset and then for edits, retain the previous offset if still ambiguous.

Comment: You may find the `ToDateTimeOffset` extensions method [I gave in this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59866718/634824) useful.