# Getting wrong UTC offset hours for exact daylight date

Tags: c#, timezone

I am trying to get the offset hours of a particular time for EST timezone like this

```
var est = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
est.GetUtcOffset(new DateTime(2020, 3, 9)).Hours;
```

This works fine and returns me `-4`, which is right for `9th March 2020` because the daylight saving changes on `8th March 2020 02:00:00`, but when I try to run the same code for date `8th March 2020 02:00:00`, it returns me `-5`, while my understanding is that from 2am of 8th march it should start returning me -4.

To get the -4, I have to run it for 3am, that is one hour after the daylight changing.

But why is it so? Why do I have to add one hour to make daylight change take effect?

Comment: Because the change makes clocks skip from 2am to 3am.

Comment: @juharr - Ah! so it skips the clock for the time difference between daylights changes! Never known this. So basically whatever hours are getting added/subtracted to the daylight time should be skipped to get the correct offset?

Comment: Yeah basically 2am to 3am when the change occurs doesn't really exist so it just gives the -5 offset if you ask about those times.  It's even worse when it changes from -4 back to -5 because the same hour occurs twice.

Comment: Got it! Thanks for this useful information. Do you know if daylight time can ever be more than one hour for any timezone?

Comment: I'm not aware of it being more than an hour anywhere, but I think there are places that do a half hour change and there are locations within timezones that do not do the change at all.

Comment: There are indeed time zones with more than an hour DST bias, but only in Antarctica and none are currently implement in Windows.  If you use .NET on other platforms such as Linux, you may encounter those.  A half-hour DST bias zone *is* in Windows, with "Lord Howe Standard Time".  Either way, I don't recommend hardcoding one hour.  Use the `ToDateTimeOffset` extension method I mention in my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

From the **Remarks** section of [the `TimeZoneInfo.GetUtcOffset` docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.getutcoffset#System_TimeZoneInfo_GetUtcOffset_System_DateTime_):

> ... If `dateTime` is ambiguous, or if the converted time is ambiguous, this method interprets the ambiguous time as a standard time. If `dateTime` is invalid, this method returns a `TimeSpan` object that reflects the difference between UTC and the time zone's standard time.

The datetime `2020-03-08 02:00:00`, is *invalid* in the US Eastern time zone, because the clocks advance from 01:59:59 to 03:00:00 on that day.  Thus, the `GetUtcOffset` uses its described behavior of returning the *standard time* offset.  You can detect this if you first call [`TimeZoneInfo.IsInvalidTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.isinvalidtime).

You might want to also use other methods from `TimeZoneInfo` to apply specific behavior.  For example, it's commonly desired in appointment scheduling scenarios to use the behavior I presented in the `ToDateTimeOffset` extension method [in this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59866718/634824).